# How can I target node with gulp-babel

Tags: node.js, gulp, coffeescript, mocha.js

I am trying to transpile my coffee code to run mocha tests inside a gulp task.

I get [BABEL] /some/path/example.js: Unknown option: .targets. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.

Here is the relevant section of the gulp task:

```
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(gulpif(isCoffee, coffee({ bare: true })))
      .pipe(babel({ presets: [
          '@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: {
              node: "11.10"
            }
          }
        ]
      } ))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
      .pipe(mocha({ reporter: 'list' }));
    }
```

And the dependencies are:

"@babel/cli": "^7.2.3"
"@babel/core": "^7.3.3"
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1"
"@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
...
"gulp": "^4.0.0"
"gulp-babel": "^8.0.0"
...

And the options are documented [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets) .

I think I must have missed a memo somewhere!

Answer (score -1):

Ah ha!  This is missing a pair of square brackets: presets should contain an array of arrays, each inner array containing a preset name and optionally a map of options.

````
        [   
          'preset-name', {
            options-key: 'option value'
          }
        ]
      ]
    })).etcetera ```
````